# React CSS transition not working

Tags: reactjs, reactcsstransitiongroup

I have a tic tac toe board, and want to add a transition an element on a click.
For demo, I have a board with some cells filled. On click on the board, a new cell is filled. I wanted this new cell to come with a transition.

I have followed the React Transition Group [doc](https://reactcommunity.org/react-transition-group/). On click on any cell of the board, a circle appears on 2rd row 3rd col. This should appear with a **Fade-in** transition. I have added CSSTransition group, but transition is not happening. Something is amiss.

Following is the codesandbox:

[image: Edit tic-tac-toe-board]

Some sample code from the snippet

**tic-tac-toe-board.js**

```js
import React from "react";
import "./tictactoe.css";

import { CSSTransition } from 'react-transition-group';

const Fade = ({ children, ...props }) => (
  <CSSTransition {...props} timeout={1000} classNames="fade">
    {children}
  </CSSTransition>
);

class TicTacToeBoard extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      board: [
        [0, 1, 0],
        [2, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0]
      ]
    };
  }

  handleBoardClick = () => {
    let newBoard = [
      [...this.state.board[0]],
      [...this.state.board[1]],
      [...this.state.board[2]]
    ];
    newBoard[1][2] = 1;
    this.setState({board: newBoard});
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="board" onClick={this.handleBoardClick}>
        {this.state.board.map((row, rowIndex) =>
          row.map((cell, colIndex) => {
            return (
              <div className="cell" key={`${rowIndex}-${colIndex}`}>
                {cell === 1 && (
                  <Fade in={true}>
                    <img
                      src="https://image.ibb.co/nDDDuw/circle_outline.png"
                      alt=""
                      className="cell-content"
                    />
                  </Fade>
                )}
                {cell === 2 && (
                  <Fade in={true}>
                    <img
                      src="https://image.ibb.co/jY0nMb/close.png"
                      alt=""
                      className="cell-content"
                    />
                  </Fade>
                )}
              </div>
            );
          })
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default TicTacToeBoard;
```

**tictactoe.css**

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.board {
  width: 90vmin;
  height: 90vmin;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px #aaa;
}

.cell {
  width: 30vmin;
  height: 30vmin;
  border: 1px solid lightgrey;
}

.cell-content {
  width: 80%;
  height: 80%;
  margin: 10%;
}

.fade-enter {
  opacity: 0.01;
}

.fade-enter.fade-enter-active {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 1000ms ease-in;
}
```

Comment: A lot of people seem to have this same question.  And yet no one seems to have answered it...

Comment: @Dave Kanter. Hi. I do not remember the exact solution for this, but I did came up with solution. At the time of question I was working on a personal project to learn React & Websockets. I was able to successfully show a transition when new component was introduced. Here are some links from that project
[Tic-Tac-Toe.js](https://github.com/live-abhishek/multiplayer-server/blob/master/ui/src/game/tic-tac-toe/tic-tac-toe.js)
& [Popout.js](https://github.com/live-abhishek/multiplayer-server/blob/master/ui/src/animations/popout.js)
Feel free to explore the project as you like.

Comment: You can also have a look at live demo of it at [Notebook Games](https://notebookgames.herokuapp.com/). But you will need a friend though to start the game (Or open in 2 tabs; there's no traffic :D). Also, project is no longer maintained. I will add answer when I get some spare time (and I recall what I did there :D, React CSS Transition are weird)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue but solved when I enclosed the `CSSTransition` inside the `TransitionGroup`

```
const Fade = ({ children, ...props }) => (
<TransitionGroup>
  <CSSTransition {...props} timeout={1000} classNames="fade">
    {children}
  </CSSTransition>
</TransitionGroup>);
```

And update the style something like this

```
.fade-enter {
  opacity: 0.01;
}

.fade-enter-active {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 1000ms ease-in;
}

.fade-exit {
  opacity: 1;
}

.fade-exit-active {
  opacity: 0.01;
  transition: opacity 1s ease-out;
}
```